# Method for finding if Path2D intersects or contains another Path2D

Tags: java, graphics, geometry

Java Path2D has only methods to determine if rectangle intersects the shape or not, and if rectangle is contained in the shape or not.  Is there an easy way to do similar things with another Path2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Area`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) instead of `Path2D`. You can determine if two areas intersect like this:

```
!a1.intersect(a2).isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but couldn't you instead use Path2D's getBounds and then just see if the bounds intersect?

E.g.

```
Path2D path1, path2;
...(paths inits)

Rectangle bounds1 = path1.getBounds();
Rectangle bounds2 = path2.getBounds();
```

Finally, check if:

```
boolean intersects = bounds1.intersects(bounds2);
```

Comment: Well, that's a good, fast, but extremely unprecise way. In that specific application, I needed something better than bounding box intersections.

Comment: This won't work with Path intersection. If the bounds of the shapes intersects this doesn't mean that the shapes itself will intersect. This is only a random guess.